# Count the amount of a specific usage in a table

Tags: mysql

That headline does not fit but I cannot think of a better one.

I have the following table:

```
timestamp | userID | role
1438953971|    5   | 6 
1438953982|    5   | 7
1438953985|    5   | 7
1438953990|    5   | 3
1438953999|    5   | 6
```

I would like to have a simple query for the number of roles used. So in this case it should be something like this:

```
role | used
 6   |  2
 7   |  2
 3   |  1
```

I know that I can do it with PHP (not how yet), but I was "experimenting" with "count(distinct(role)) AS used" but that does not seem right.

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ROLE, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ROLE ORDER BY ROLE;
```